# How to remove/disable styling on some bootstrap elements

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know if it is possible to disable styling on a specific html element.

In my case it is a input text. I cannot resize it. I went through the bootstrap css and found it has padding. I tried to use `padding: none` and `0 0 0 0` plus `!important` and it did not work.

Is possible to disable the styling for that specific item?

Comment: you can use a <span></span> for that particular element or just make a new style id or class for what you want to change

Comment: If i recall correctly they use height on the inputs 20px i belive try to change the height of the element.

Comment: Can you post your code, so that we can have a point of reference on "html element" and the CSS that you've tried?

Comment: Keith I tried spanning and using a class on the text does not help a lot. idavid I tried and it does not work.

Comment: !important is a sign of failure. Read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Maybe you should look for the style that it gets before trying padding. Each browser has its own limit and ways to style form elements. It could be something else, like line-height ...

Answer (score 6):

As of Bootstrap 3, you'd use the `list-unstyled` class to achieve this.

Example:

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Plus one for providing a bootstrap solution to a bootstrap tagged question.

Comment: @abaelter
What do you mean by "having to use a class for zero styling" ?

Comment: Just criticism of bootstrap, not your answer. Don't like the fact that you have to use a class to get an unstyled element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You can achieve it in following way:

- Load your own `stylesheet` definition after the `bootstrap.css`. For your case define `input[type=text]{padding:0px;}` must call after the `bootstrap's` css file(s).
- If you want to use in-line css you can try: `<input type="text" style="padding:0px" />`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

in the 'head' of your HTML change the order of the local css file and bootstrap css, the local css should be the after the bootstrap css:

```
<head>

   <!-- bootstrap css is the first here -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- bootstrap css is the last -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


</head>
```

now if you applied !important in your css it should work.

another solution is to apply your css inline `<element style="padding:0"></element>`

Answer (score 0):

Set it in the style of the element in the style attribrute if an item is there it has priority.

Also if you want to be double sure add !important as well

Answer (score -1):

Would Javascript be of any help to you? If so the .`setAttribute` native javascript function can help:

http://jsfiddle.net/nMJjS/1/

Just replace the id that I made up with the id of input element you want to change