# Prevent bootstrap for a particular dom by adding some data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to twitter bootstrap. And I want to know that is there a way to prevent applying any bootstrap CSS or JS to a DOM and all it's children by adding some attribute.

Like

```
<div class="col-lg-9">Bootstrap applied</div>

<div data-no-bootstrap="true">
    No boot strap should applied in this dom
</div>
```

It may sounds very odd. But I would like to know is there any way or not.

Comment: How your bootstrap styles are being applied on these elements?

Comment: TWBS has hundreds lines of code and overriding them could cause headache.

Comment: Actually I was using a wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/share-this/ share-this . But when I use that plugin in default theme it is perfect.But if I used in a custom theme with bootstrap then the social icons are get cutted from bottom.That's why I decided to prevent applying any bootstrap effect on that particular dom.How ever I have did with overriding the css.Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at this post:
[How to remove/disable styling on some bootstrap elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751430/how-to-remove-disable-styling-on-some-bootstrap-elements)

1. It is possible to override styling for certain elements by adding your own custom styles.
2. This approach is not how bootstrap works.

The library itself is designed to only apply to the elements you want to be styled.
Because unless you explicitly use the bootstrap classes there would be no styling of your elements.
There are some exceptions of course, where it could be necessary to override the styles.

But there is no general rule that I know of.